# Samsung NVMe 2TB drive "toast"?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clonezilla, disk-cloning

I've had this drive as my OS+data drive for about 10 months. It just apparently died on me. The computer was running Windows 10 and had a BSOD. When I booted it up, the drive was detected but not booting. My computer booted to the old Windows install on another drive and I was able to see that it has attribute `Current Read Only = True` and from Samsung Magician I see critical condition:

[image: critical condition]

With SMART errors:

[image]

When I try to clone the drive with CloneZilla or EaseUS Partition Master it aborts partway through (very early, like < 5%). I tried with both regular mode in Clonezilla and sector-by-sector mode (and of course I had -rescue mode on to continue after bad sectors; actually it was able to copy other partitions like recovery and EFI even though those had some bad sectors).

From a forum post on Samsung's support board I learned that the SSD being in Current Read Only mode without the Read Only attribute set means the drive's write capability has worn out. But this drive only has 12.5TBW! And the drive still has 200GB of free space so I don't understand why over-provisioning didn't take over to replace bad sectors. And why would losing write capability affect my ability to CLONE the drive anyway? :(

I assume I'll be able to get a replacement from Samsung under warranty. When I do, I'd like to just be able to clone the old drive back onto the new one. But with the data corruption (which I don't understand) that doesn't seem possible. I'm wondering if the data corruption is due to the filesystem being corrupted (like maybe the drive has forgotten which sectors it already marked as bad), which I can't fix because the drive is read only! If I could copy the filesystem to another drive I could try to fix it, but it won't finish the copy! Catch 22?

Comment: What kind of SMART data is that? "Media Errors" is not a [Known ATA S.M.A.R.T. attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes).

Comment: Different attributes for NVMe drives apparently (for Samsung, at least): https://uxd.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004396211-S-M-A-R-T-Attributes-Table-supported-by-Samsung-NVMe-Drives-

Comment: I booted up SystemRescueCD instead of CloneZilla and ddrescue seems to be doing a better job than CloneZilla at skipping errors. Made it past 5% anyway...

Comment: If some errors are intermittent, you may run ddrescue multiple times to improve the result.

Comment: Do you think these read errors are blocks that the SSD had previously marked as worn out but that somehow got forgotten when the drive went into recovery (read only) mode?

Comment: ddrescue is also MUCH faster than CloneZilla. Estimates 4 hours for the 2TB drive instead of CloneZilla's 10+ hours.

Comment: They are probably unrecoverable errors, meaning unsalvageable. The drive usually goes into read only mode when it does manage to salvage the sectors, but there are too many, so the spare sectors are exhausted.

Comment: I thought these drives are supposed to use free space for spare sectors when available? As I said there are 200GB free. :/ So far ddrescue has read 230GB and only 5MB have errors.

Comment: The spare sectors are only visible to the firmware. Windows doesn't know about them.